# Looking for a method in UIPageViewController like scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController. I want to pop back to the root navigation controller when I read the last page. So far I am using:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

    NSUInteger index = ((TutorialContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.images count]+1) {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        return nil;

    }



    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

to pop it. It seem a little buggy though, some times it pops it sometimes it doesn't I think I need to place `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];` elsewhere. Is there a method like scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: in UIScrollView that I can use to trigger it when it stops scrolling to the last page? Any pointers would be really appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate of the scroll view used by the UIPageViewController.

```
for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
     if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
         [(UIScrollView *)view setDelegate:self];
     }
 }
```

And then implement the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method to check the page index and pop back to the root view controller from there.